# IndexError in Python (Beginner)

Tags: python, debugging

I have an array X[1]. In that array, I want to replace elements [...,1,0,...] with [....,10,..]. In other words, wherever 1 and 0 occur consecutively, I want to replace it with 10.

My code is,

```
for m in range(0,len(X[1])):

    if X[1][m] == 0:
        X[1].insert(m-1,10)
        del X[1][m]
        del X[1][m]
```

But this code gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gettinginput.py", line 25, in <module>
    if X[1][m] == 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I remove one the two delete statements, it doesn't give me an error, and it removes `1` from `[...,1,0,...]` but leaves the `0`.

eg.

```
X[1] = [5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1]
```

After removing 1 delete statement, output is

```
[5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 10, 0, 3, 2, 1]
```

But with 2 delete statements, I get an error.

Comment: is the '`' in your actual code or just the sample? X[1].insert(m-1,10)`

Comment: What is the content of your array? I've never seen an example where an array is denoted X[1]. That tells me you have a list with the element 1 in it, and that would be X = [1]. It would be helpful to post a sample of your array.

Comment: Sorry, ` is not part of the code.
I have given the example. Actually array X has multiple items. I am first dealing with X[1].

Comment: If you delete 2 items from an array and only insert 1, of course you're going to run off the end of the array if you don't also adjust the number you stop at.

Answer (score 2):

```
def reduce_list(lst, match, replace):
    _matchlen = len(match)
    lst = list(lst)                      # copy existing list
    for i in xrange(len(lst)-_matchlen, -1, -1):   # scan through it backwards
        if lst[i:i+_matchlen] == match:
            lst[i:i+_matchlen] = replace
    return lst

print reduce_list([1,0,1,0,1,1,0], [1,0], [10])
```

results in

```
[10, 10, 1, 10]
```

To match your example,

```
X[1] = reduce_array(X[1], [1,0], [10])
```

**Edit:** after thinking about it a bit more,

```
def reduce_list(lst, match, replace):
    """
    Return a new list,
    with all original non-overlapping occurrences of 'match'
    replaced by 'replace'
    """
    lst = list(lst)                      # copy existing list
    matchlen = len(match)
    replacelen = len(replace)
    last_i = len(lst) - matchlen
    i = 0
    while i <= last_i:
        if lst[i:i+matchlen] == match:
            lst[i:i+matchlen] = replace
            last_i += replacelen - matchlen
            i += replacelen
        else:
            i += 1
    return lst
```

Comment: Why `_matchlen` instead of `matchlen`?  This isn't a class, so there's no reason to protect matchlen.  Also, what do you gain by iterating over this backward?  However, +1 for the function and not changing the input list (as my answer does).

Answer (score 1):

On the first iteration of your loop, `m == 0`.  Then you do an insert into `m-1`, which will be `-1`, which is most certainly out of range of `X[1]`.

```
for m in range(0,len(X[1])):
    if X[1][m] == 0:
        X[1].insert(m-1,10)
        del X[1][m]
        del X[1][m]
```

Edit: If the input starts with a `0`, my original answer stands.  Assuming it never does as the OP suggests, let's look at why the two deletes cause a problem.

```
X[1] = [5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1]
```

The for loop evaluates to `for m in range(0, 10)`.  When we reach the `0`, `m == 6`.  So we insert `10` before position `5`*, and delete position `6` twice.

```
X[1] = [5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 10, 3, 2, 1]
```

Notice there are only 9 elements in there?  The `len(X[1])` in your `for` loop **is never re-evaluated**, so it's going to run off the end of the array, giving your out of range error.

Test program:

```
>>> for m in range(len(x)):
...     del(x[m])
...     print(len(x))
...
8
7
6
5
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

---

*Why **before** position 5?  From the definition of `insert`:

> list.insert(i, x)
>
> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

Comment: '0' will never be the first element of the array. And if thats the case, why does it work when there is only one delete statement.

Comment: Thanks. I understood my mistake. One easy way to correct I found is to have a counter to count the number of such situations in the array, and then
    
`for z in range(0, count):
    X[1].remove(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way.

```
lst=[5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1]

for idx,val in enumerate(lst[:-1]):
    if(val==1 and lst[idx+1]==0):
        lst[idx:idx+1]=[10]

print (lst)
```

Or without `enumerate`:

```
for idx in range(len(lst)-1):
    if(lst[idx:idx+1]==[1,0]):
        lst[idx:idx+1]=[10]

print (lst)
```

We search over the list looking for a sublist [1,0] and then replace that sublist with the (sub)list [10].

Of course, before doing all this, if you have a list of lists (`X`) as you call it, you could do `lst=X[1]` instead of `lst=[...]`